# Problem with the installation of synaptic from command line

Tags: software-installation, synaptic

I can't install Synaptic package manager from command line. When I try to install it, it shows...

```
$ sudo apt-get install synaptic

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: You should give more details about the distribution you're using. Also, maybe try to show us the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. It will help us figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a distribution like Ubuntu (Xubuntu 13.04, *raring* here), the [synaptic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/synaptic) package is part of the *universe* section ("Community-mainained free and open-source software") which may not be enabled by default in your case. So you may need to enable access to that source like so described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134506/e-package-synaptic-has-no-installation-candidate-when-trying-to-install-syn) for instance. First, if you're doing this with a terminal, you may check the /etc/apt/sources.list file to see if you find any reference to "universe" and if not you may need to modify or add some entries. For example, in my sources.list file, I can find the following "universe" related entries:

> deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
>
> deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
>
> deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
>
> deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
>
> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
>
> deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe

Depending on your distribution and its release version, the entries may vary. You may try [apt-cache](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/apt-cache.8.html) with the `apt-cache search --full synaptic` command to see any available package which you have access to and which references "synaptic" somehow. Finally, websites usually maintain [search engines](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) to allow you to figure out the contents of their repositories and which section a package belongs to and its dependencies, which in turn offers guidance for modifying the sources.list file.

Generally, see [managing repositories from the command line with Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine).